# How to get data from Google Spreadsheet to HTML as a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create webapp with html service. Here is my code.

The code in `code.gs` file.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('userendhtml')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxx'); 
var rawData =  sss.getDataRange().getValues()     
var data = []                       
for (var i = 0; i< rawData.length; i++){

data.push(rawData[i])

}
  return data
}
```

Now I want to access this data as javascript variable for further processing (for creating table with querying). The code in `userendhtml.html` is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<script>
 var data2 = getData();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't store data to variable `data2`. So how to get data from spreadsheet in variable in javascript?

Comment: Take a look at [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) in conjunction with [`withSuccessHandler(...)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var data2;

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
        data2 = ret;
      }).getData();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I accidentally edit one of your answer again.  I have to be more careful.  I removed it thought sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the techniques found in the Templated Html reference that I gave you. But you could also do this:

```
<script>
  var data2;
window.onload=function(){
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(dt){
    data2=dt;
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML=data2;
  .getData();
}
</script>
```

The templated html approach loads on the server and this approach loads after the dom loads.

I just tested this example as a dialog

```
    function dialogTest() {
      var html='<div id="mydiv"></div>';
      html+='<script>var data2;window.onload=function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dt){data2=dt;document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=data2;}).getMtData();}</script>';
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Dialog Test');
    }

    function getMtData() {
      return 'Hello World';
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I add alert(data2) it gives undefined. It means that data is not parsed to variable data2.

Comment: Where did you perform alert(data2)?

Comment: Just before `</script>` in your code. After curly braces `}`.

Comment: Well that happens before the DOM is loaded so that's no surprise then.

Comment: So how can I use `data2` for further processing in html? Say If I want to do `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = data2`. If it is not available in script for further use, there would be no use of `data2`.

Comment: Take a look at my answer.  You could also utilize it in a function that is initiated from a user event.  I use this a lot when I want to load a drop down list from a spreadsheet.